# Assembly MOV and dereferencing

Tags: assembly, x86-64, dereference

I came across this line from a textbook.

```
mov var, 10                   ;var contains 1 at 0xA

mov RAX, [var+5]              ;This will add 5 to the address already held by var, then dereference the new address and put whatever is at that address into RAX.
```

So the steps taken will be

1. Calculate new Address
2. Dereference new address to get value stored in memory location

For step1, will they use (`0x1 from the value(1) + 5`)
OR (`10 from address(0xA) + 5`)?
What would be the answer for Step1 ?

Comment: *address already held by var* is a confusing way to state it. It sounds like it's talking about the data from memory, but it's not; x86 doesn't have memory-indirect addressing modes.  Assuming `var` is a label in `.data` or `.bss`, e.g. `extern char var[]`, it's actually just accessing memory at 5 + symbol address.  e.g. like C `(&rax, &var[5], 8)`, except of course rax is a register.  So the address math is all done at assemble time, assembling to an instruction with a `[disp32]` or `[RIP+rel32]` [addressing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101) which will access `var+5`.

Comment: Also, wait a minute, `;var contains 1 at 0xA` makes no sense.  The only way `mov var, 10` will assemble is with `10` (0xA) as the value.  And only in MASM syntax where bare `var` is the same as `[var]`, and can imply an operand-size for the store.  There's no `1` anywhere, either as an offset to the symbol address or as an immediate value.

Comment: There are two possibilities: var is a register (e.g. by defining a macro called var), then the address is 15. Or var is a memory address, then the calculated address is the address of var + 5 bytes.

Comment: I think the best way to explain is that `var` doesn't *hold* an address, it *is* an address.  The fact that you can `mov var, 10` instead of having to write `mov qword [var], 10` or `mov qword [var+0], 10` is just MASM being weird.

Comment: It's possible that `var` is not even an address, but an expression, such as `var = [bp + 1111]`. I don't remember the syntax, or which assembler, but this was a possibility to define variables 30 years ago. From this expression it's possible to construct new addresses in confusing ways, just like `a[1] == 1[a]` in C. `var + 5` would be `[bp + 1111] + 5 == [bp + 1116]`.